# How to prevent unwrapping of nested SCSS rules in output CSS?

Tags: css, sass, nested, css-selectors

Recent browsers has good support of nested CSS (https://caniuse.com/css-nesting).

Is there some option for keeping nested rules as is, in some compiler?

A proposal for DART SASS, see https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/main/proposal/plain-css-nesting.md

Input SCSS example:

```
$r: red;
.c1 {
  .c2 { color: $r; }
}
```

Output example:

```
.c1 {
  &.c2 { color: red; }
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure about if there are any options for this in the compiler yet. And as of July 2023, caniuse shows only approximately 72% which I wouldn’t classify as “good” as this only began being supported by browsers this year and typical users don’t update their software as much as the SO community do (example: https://www.statista.com/statistics/271774/share-of-android-platforms-on-mobile-devices-with-android-os/ ) (sorry for the opinion part) I would say that good coverage has to be at least 2 years and well above 85% coverage, and even that is debatably low